# Obter dados em uma rota PUT usando silex

Tags: php, http, silex

Gostaria de saber como pode-se obter dados passados para uma rota *put* usando o silex. 
Por exemplo :

```
$app->put('foo/{id}', function(Request $request, $id) use ($app){
  return var_dump($request->get('bar')); //return null 
});
```

Isso retorna `NULL`, alguém sabe uma forma de se obter os dados passados pela requisição ?

Comment: Como você está passando seus dados? Via form data? Via json?

Comment: Via json, estou usando o POSTMAN do google chrome para testar, e via curl, com o seguinte cabeçalho

Content-Type: text/json

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a [documentação do Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/cookbook/json_request_body.html), você tem que instruir sua aplicação a aceitar uma requisição via JSON:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag;

$app->before(function (Request $request) {
    if (0 === strpos($request->headers->get('Content-Type'), 'application/json')) {
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        $request->request->replace(is_array($data) ? $data : array());
    }
});
```

**Edit:** segue um exemplo funcional:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->before(function(Request $request) {
    if (0 === strpos($request->headers->get('Content-Type'), 'application/json')) {
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        $request->request->replace(is_array($data) ? $data : []);
    }
});

$app->put('/foo/{id}', function(Request $request, $id) use($app) {
    var_dump($request->request->all()); die;
});

$app->run();
```

Usei o [HTTPie](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie) para testar a requisição:

```
$ echo '{ "lala": "lele" }' | http PUT silex.dev/foo/1
```

Resposta:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 45
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Tue, 28 Apr 2015 13:46:47 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) PHP/5.5.20
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.20

array(1) {
  ["lala"]=>
  string(4) "lele"
}
```

Comment: Então, eu cheguei a fazer tal procedimento, e funciona perfeitamente para rotas POST, no entanto quando a rota é PUT o mesmo parece não fazer efeito....

Comment: O que aparece no dump do seguinte método: `$request->request->all()` ?

Comment: Retorna um array vazio

Comment: Complementei a resposta com um exemplo funcional. Aqui recebeu a requisição via `PUT` normalmente.